# Atalho no VScode para acessar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Estou tentando achar um atalho no VScode para acessar o arquivo css, js, etc... de uma pagina. Por exemplo estou com um arquivo HTML aberto onde eu tenho a linha abaixo

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funcoes-list-configuracoes-gerais.js"></script>
```

Como eu acesso o arquivo funcoes-list-configuracoes-gerais.js para editar sem ter que procurar o arquivo no explorador. Qual atalho uso para somente clicar e abrir o arquivo para editar?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Basta segurar o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+e clicar. Cuidado apenas com os caminhos relativos do projeto.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).